# Удаление элемента из вектора пар

Tags: c++, vector

Имеется вектор пар :

```
vector<pair<int,string>>temp2;
```

Необходимо из данного вектора удалить элемент по условному индексу i.

temp2.erase(i) не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erase использует итератор. А значит где так

```
temp2.erase(temp.begin()+i);
```